# Constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints

```
CREATE TABLE classname (
class_name VARCHAR2(5) CONSTRAINT class_name_pk PRIMARY KEY,
meet_at_and_timing VARCHAR2(30),
room_no VARCHAR2(5),
faculty_handling NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT faculty_handling_fk REFERENCES faculty(faculty_id)
);
```

in the above table creation the room_number should always contain "LH" as first two characters.

**Example:**

```
room_no=LH43 is valid but room_no=EC43 is invalid...
```

how should i specify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple syntax would be:

```
alter table classname
 add constraint check_room_no 
  check (room_no like 'LH%');
```

I prefer this method because if you were querying for strings beginning LH then you'd most likely use this, not SubStr()

Answer (score 4):

I guess it will be simpler

```
alter table classname
     add constraint check_room_no 
      check (SUBSTR(room_no, 1, 2) = 'LH');
```

Comment: This is easier to understand and will also perform better than the RegEx version (although the difference will be hard to detect unless we're inserting a *lot* of rows ).

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I got the answer after thinking a lot.

Answer (score 2):

All three solutions are good. I've created a test table with 200 millon rows and measured the time it takes to add a check constraint:

```
 36.4s  0.17 us   CHECK (room_no LIKE 'LH%')
 54.2s  0.26 us   CHECK (substr(room_no,1,2) = 'LH') 
111.9s  0.54 us   CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(room_no, '^LH', 'c'))
138.3s  0.66 us   CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(room_no, '^LH', 'i'))
```

Comment: I guess it depends on indexes. Probably you have an index on column room_no. You can make function-based index on substr(room_no, 1, 2) and performance must be great :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of REGEXP_LIKE. If you want "LH" uppercase, you should specify it is case sensitive in REGEXP_LIKE.

```
alter table classname
     add constraint check_room_no 
      check (REGEXP_LIKE(room_no,'your_regex_goes_here','C'));
```

Then you figure out what the regex is for your constraint by playing with http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ for instance.

example :

```
 alter table classname
    add constraint check_room_no 
      check (REGEXP_LIKE(room_no,'^LH\w','C'));
```